# Почему длина ответа - едва ли не основной критерий качества? Кто так решил?

Tags: обсуждение

Частенько читаю:

> > *Данный ответ отмечен как «низкокачественный» из-за длины и содержимого.*

Про содержимое понятно, но обратите внимание: на первом месте длина. Допустим, "запятая не нужна - нет причин для постановки" - о, это низкокачественный ответ! Ибо нужно объяснить, почему дважды два четыре, а также осветить историю вопроса прямо от древних шумеров и ацтеков, а также указать случаи, когда дважды два будет не четыре, а четыре с минусом, и вот это как раз будет научно, а короткий ответ - это не научно, это по-рабоче-крестьянски, мы этого не любим.

Шутки в сторону! Почему развернутый ответ может быть хуже короткого?

Первое. Он почти всегда ориентирован не на автора вопроса, а исключительно на себя любимого. Вот я какой! Кто-нибудь будет спорить? )

Второе. Очень часто спрашивающего интересует чисто утилитарная сторона дела: нужна запятая или нет, вот да или нет? Он понятия не имеет о теме и реме, о предикатах, и о препозициях и постпозициях, и об именительном темы... Ну и зачем это всё?

Третье. Практически все мы, сами собой любимые, здесь любители. Хотя и грамотные люди, но все же любители. О специалистах все в курсе, и вот парадокс: как раз специалисты-то и дают довольно краткие ответы. Ничего лишнего! А любитель разведет турусы на колесах, причем подчас совершенно не по теме, причем добавит "на мой взгляд, на мой вкус", процитирует Нацкорпус (а там можно найти почти всё, что угодно) - нешто его ответ станет от этого лучше? Он станет хуже.

Запятая не нужна: нет причин для постановки. Можно добавить: пауза в устной речи не является основанием для запятой. Всё!

Запятая нужна: сложноподчиненное предложение. [Ссылка на Розенталя] (Розенталь лучше объяснит, да оно и авторитетнее, верно?) Всё!

И так далее, и тому подобное.

Comment: Фраза "запятая не нужна, нет причин для постановки" мне нравится: коротко и ясно. Для постановки любого знака нужны основания, причины. А если таковых нет, зачем ставить знак? Согласна с Вами.

Comment: A почему вы не учитываете то, что сюда может зайти любой и ответить вашей же фразой: "Для постановки запятой нет оснований" и ошибется. И задавший вопрос примет его за правильный.

Comment: @Серж, как будто нельзя вылить море воды и все равно ошибиться... Конечно, бывают тут ошибки. И на солнце бывают пятна, то есть, пардон, и Грамота, бывает, ошибается.

Comment: В том-то и дело. Поэтому, где это возможно, лучше дать полный ответ.  На те вопросы, которые я не могу обосновать,т. е. дать ссылку и привести правило, я не отвечаю.

Comment: @Серж, где есть правила на *непостановку* знаков препинания?! Выходит, непостановку обосновать вообще нельзя?

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно обосновать, например, отсутствие запятой в ССП, в СПП перед союзом. Труднее, конечно, обосновать отсутствие знаков препинания в простом нераспространенном предложении.

Comment: @Серж, так это и есть наиболее частые вопросы - о запятых в простых предложениях. Часто их втыкают там, где пауза в устной речи.

Comment: @Niemand Правило такое. В простом неосложненном предложении запятые не ставятся, хотя в нем могут присутствовать речевые паузы. Но надо доказать, что это предложение именно простое неосложненное, а не только сказать,  что нет оснований для постановки запятой.

Comment: @Sharon Боже мой... Вы бы и для шестиклассников "доказывали" такими словами, как препозиция и детерминант? Какое же это доказательство? Это жонглирование "умными" словами.

Comment: @Niemand  Термин "детерминант", будто бы совершенно "недоступный" для современного шестиклассника, - это важное понятие  при изучении пунктуации. Детерминант (здесь обстоятельственный оборот в начале предложения) относится не к конкретному слову, а ко всему предложению, поэтому он обладает определенной самостоятельностью и часто обозначается произносительной паузой. Именно поэтому  возникает вопрос о его обособлении. Доказывать здесь ничего не нужно, надо просто знать, что падежная форма обычно не обособляется, но факультативно  обособляется оборот с производными предлогами.

Comment: @Sharon Что-то я в справочниках термина "детерминант" не видел. А уж авторы - ученые до мозга костей. Поэтому и здесь не пристало щеголять подобными терминами. Не надо объяснять мудрёно то, что можно объяснить просто.

Comment: Наберите в поисковике это слово, и вы всё будете знать о детерминанте. Термин «детерминант»  (дословно "определяющий") в русистике введён в середине 60‑х гг. Н. Ю. Шведовой.  Свободная словоформа, находящаяся обычно в начале предложения и осуществляющая грамматическую связь со всей последующей предикативной единицей, являясь ее распространителем.https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/348/детерминант  Из-за этой относительной свободы часто встает вопрос об обособлении обстоятельственного оборота (детерминанта) в начале предложения.  В своем ответе я привожу этот термин в скобках.

Comment: Это уж, пожалуйста, сами. Вы уже взрослый, как-нибудь разберетесь. На этом наш диалог считаю законченным, благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 7):

Конечно, **качество ответа на первом месте**. Хороший ответ может быть как коротким, так и длинным. Обобщения здесь не нужны. 
  Но обычно  качественный ответ не умещается в одно предложение вида  "запятая здесь не нужна".

**Всё остальное, на мой взгляд, неверно.**

**Довод 1. Не судите, да не судимы будете.**

**Не надо всех мерить своей меркой.** Лично я не ориентирую свои ответы на себя, для меня важнее понять смысл вопроса и помочь человеку его решить. Все амбиции при ответе  в сторону. Если потом скажут спасибо, тогда приятно, тогда и можно подумать на тему  "вот какая я хорошая".

Довод 2. Чаще спрашивают о том, **нужна ли запятая и почему. Без обоснования ответ вообще ничего не стоит.** Кроме того, читают ответы и другие люди, поэтому хороший и обоснованный ответ – это важная информационная составляющая нашего сайта.

Довод 3. **Любители часто отвечают лучше профессионалов.** Да и кто они, профессионалы? Журналист, писатель – это профессионалы? Юрист – это профессионал? Грамотная речь нужна людям многих профессий, а не только учителям и лингвистам-филологам.

Из опыта работы на сайте могу сказать, что ответы тех, кого Вы считаете любителем, **часто намного грамотнее профессиональных ответов.**

Возьмите хотя бы ваш слоган "для постановки запятой нет оснований". **Да он в корне неверен**, хотя **вроде бы профессионал его поддержал.**

**Запятая не ставится в простом неосложненном предложении**, при этом  предложение может быть распространенным. В нем могут быть произносительные паузы и почти всегда есть пауза, обозначающая перелом интонации. Люди слышат эти паузы, им кажется, что там должна быть запятая. **Надо понять, где человек слышит паузу и объяснить, почему она не обозначается запятой.** Проблема постановки "лишних запятых" весьма актуальна.

**Вот и надо обозначить грамматику предложения** и показать, что все члены входят в состав предложения, надо объяснить, почему они не обособляются.

Не далее как сегодня я отвечала на вопрос об обособлении детерминанта. Я объяснила, почему предложный оборот не обособляется и  когда возможно обособление. Я думаю, что это **полезная информация** для автора вопроса и для всех остальных.

**И ссылки часто нужны**, Розенталь здесь незаменим. Людям надо обоснованное решение, а ссылка на ПАС или Розенталя – это ссылка на официальный источник. Ответ получает дополнительную ценность и может использоваться в качестве аргумента.

Comment: *>> Да и кто они, профессионалы? Журналист, писатель – это профессионалы? Юрист – это профессионал?* А вы здесь разве не видите профессионалов? Я - вижу, причем это видно буквально сразу, по одному ответу можно определить. *И ссылки часто нужны* - а кто с этим спорит? Как раз об этом мой последний абзац. А вы думали, ирония? )

PS А вы правильно многое на свой счет приняли, ибо как раз и грешите многословностью. Еще забыл в вопросе высказаться **вот про такое**. Этим тоже не стоит злоупотреблять.

Comment: Не решайте за всех, решайте за себя. Напишите в графе "о себе": я ясновидящий.  Также могу заметить, что ссылки в ваших ответах присутствуют в единичных случаях, обычно говорится о чувствах. Может, вы и правда ясновидящий, тогда Вам надо на другой форум. Здесь же ясновидение не в цене.

Comment: зато здесь в цене вот такое: *Обстоятельственный оборот в препозиции (детерминант)...* - и это, заметьте, на простейшую школьную фразу. Что это, как не "Довод 1"? Профессионалы такого себе не позволяют. )

Comment: Вопрос вроде бы не из школьного учебника. А Вам какие слова непонятны: оборот, обстоятельство, препозиция, обособляется? Наверное, препозиция?  Это значит "в начале предложения". Я буду теперь так писать.

Comment: А еще Вы меня "профессионалами"  немного утомили. Надо узнать в справке, можно ли Вам "клеить на участников форума такие ярлыки".

Comment: Вопрос именно "из школьного учебника". При ошибке оценка восьмикласснику снижается на балл, а я бы и на два. Но, чтобы написать правильно, никаких препозиций не требуется. Кстати, "препозиция" вовсе не означает "в начале предложения".

Comment: @Niemand, ваш дискурс инклюдирует гиперболическое количество слов _профессионал_ и его когнатов. Офферирую интераптировать дискуссию в таких терминах и свичнуться к дифферентному лексикону.

Answer (score 5):

Отмечает низкокачественным автоматика, а дальше уже пользователи решают, можно ли эту фразу считать ответом или нет.  Да, иногда и мне попадались вопросы, на которые можно было ответить вообще одним-двумя словами, например по правильному ударению.

Почему же тогда правила сообщества **не рекомендуют** отвечать слишком кратко, добавив ссылку в конце?

- Содержание сторонних сайтов может измениться: сегодня там правила Розенталя, завтра — гимн во славу Кетцалькоатля; лучше, если в ответе будет продублировано место, на которое вы ссылаетесь, заодно будет понятно, что вы имеете в виду.
- Непрофессионалу, как вы верно заметили, часто бывает сложно разобраться в многочисленных терминах, используемых для объяснения тех или иных правил. Получив от вас лишь ответ на конкретный вопрос, человек не сможет применить его для другого подобного случая. Например, на вопрос "Как писать "Я боюсь ошибит(ь)ся"?" можно просто ответить "-ться", но гораздо лучше расписать, в каких случаях мягкий знак пишется, а в каких нет.
- Как новичку отличить профессионала от дилетанта? Если из развёрнутого ответа можно получить какое-то представление о знаниях и уровне подготовки человека, то краткий ответ может написать как академик, так и первоклассник Вася. Да, часть терминов в объяснении конкретной проблемы может быть непонятной, но само наличие этих терминов может помочь в поиске самостоятельного решения. Не зная термина "этимология", найти происхождение того или иного слова не так-то просто.

Comment: То есть, все решает робот, по количеству знаков?! Простим его, ибо не ведает, что творит. Длина ответа вообще не должна иметь значения. Я предпочитаю _прямые_ и конкретные (без отвлекающих отступлений) ответы  на вопрос, с доказательствами и ссылками - только в меру необходимости.

Comment: @Alex_ander всё решают участники сообщества, робот лишь указывает на возможно некачественные ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, я считаю, основная проблема в неправильном понимании формата форумов stackexchange. Он отличается от формата справки Грамота.ру, где каждый вопрос получает краткий ответ профессионалов (в редчайших случаях он может быть ошибочным, но разговор не об этом). На площадках stackexchange предполагается, что ответ должен содержать достаточное объяснение, по которому любой другой пользователь (пассивный участник) смог бы самостоятельно разобраться со своим похожим вопросом. А какую он может получить пользу от неаргументированного мнения, пусть даже высказанного опытным участником?

Конкретно по проблеме слишком коротких ответов. Иногда такие ответы действительно уместны и достаточны, но только при условии, что они верны и не требуют дополнительной аргументации. Пример: автор вопроса однажды спросил, верна ли его подробная аргументация в какой-то конкретной ситуации. Я тогда счёл односложный утвердительный ответ вполне уместным. (Правда, всё равно получил замечание, но и обижаться не стал.)

Мы знаем, что на форуме есть несколько участников, способных дать аккуратный, развёрнутый ответ даже простой вопрос. Эти ответы приятно читать; по ним можно изучать язык; их легко оценивать по формальным признакам, а не только по тому, совпали ли наши эмоции. Вообще, я считаю, что было бы лучше минусовать ответы, содержащие только голословные мнения. К сожалению, нас здесь слишком мало, чтобы применять такие жёсткие критерии, но вот что мне совсем не понятно: зачем пытаться конкурировать с участниками, умеющими отвечать на простые вопросы? Ведь есть же сложные и неоднозначные темы, где можно при желании и себя показать и с ними поспорить. А делать это так, как в здешних комментариях — это, скажем так, не совсем "спортивно".

Comment: Вот-вот, "себя показать" - это ключевые слова. Простейший вопрос (а таких здесь если не большинство, то половина уж точно) - но на нем себя не покажешь: нужна всего пара предложений, отсылка к справочнику, и всё. Но показать очень хочется! И в ход идет все: мудреные термины, жирный шрифт, ответ на целую страницу и т.д. и т.п.